# the lambda evaluation in the python implementation of scheme interpreter problem from CS61a

Tags: python, scheme, interpreter

I am now following [Berkeley 61a (version 2023)](https://cs61a.org/proj/scheme/#problem-9-2-pt) to learn computer science. I got stuck with the problem 9 of the scheme project, and I couldn't figure out where I got wrong. And this is the first time I do a big project like this, I find it difficult to debug effectively.

Someone help me with this?

This is the code in my [github](https://github.com/EllenInCalifornia/cs61A/tree/dace664c5df3425e486275cc5c77eb0c8f95845a/projects/scheme). Problem9 is located in scheme_eval_apply.py. this is the code of this particular file:

```
def scheme_eval(expr, env, _=None):  # Optional third argument is ignored
    """Evaluate Scheme expression EXPR in Frame ENV.
    >>> expr = read_line('(+ 2 2)')
    >>> expr
    Pair('+', Pair(2, Pair(2, nil)))
    >>> scheme_eval(expr, create_global_frame())
    4
    """
    # Evaluate atoms
    if scheme_symbolp(expr):
        return env.lookup(expr)
    elif self_evaluating(expr):
        return expr
 
    # All non-atomic expressions are lists (combinations)
    if not scheme_listp(expr):
        raise SchemeError('malformed list: {0}'.format(repl_str(expr)))
    first, rest = expr.first, expr.rest
    if scheme_symbolp(first) and first in scheme_forms.SPECIAL_FORMS:
        return scheme_forms.SPECIAL_FORMS[first](rest, env)
    else:
        '''scheme_eval(Pair('+', Pair(2, Pair(2, nil))), create_global_frame())
         expr = read_line('(+ (+ 2 2) (+ 1 3) (* 1 4))') 
        '''
        # in map function, mapped = fn(self.first), but scheme_eval has two arguments
        operator = scheme_eval(expr.first, env)
        # probleme9 这里很可能是有问题的
        # if isinstance(operator, LambdaProcedure):
        #     return scheme_apply(operator, expr.rest, env)
        operands = expr.rest.map(lambda x: scheme_eval(x, env))
        return scheme_apply(operator, operands, env)
 
 
 
def scheme_apply(procedure, args, env):
    """Apply Scheme PROCEDURE to argument values ARGS (a Scheme list) in
    Frame ENV, the current environment."""
    validate_procedure(procedure)
    if not isinstance(env, Frame):
       assert False, "Not a Frame: {}".format(env)
    if isinstance(procedure, BuiltinProcedure):
 
        func = procedure.py_func
        argu = []
        while args != nil:
            argu.append(args.first)
            args = args.rest
 
        try:
            if procedure.need_env:
                return func(*argu, env)
            else:
                return func(*argu)
        except TypeError as err:
            raise SchemeError('incorrect number of arguments: {0}'.format(procedure))
    elif isinstance(procedure, LambdaProcedure):
        # PROBLEM 9
        formals = procedure.formals
        # vals = args.map(lambda x: scheme_eval(x, env))
        current_frame = env.make_child_frame(formals, args)
        return eval_all(procedure.body, current_frame)
 
        # END PROBLEM 9
```

and this is error report I got from the terminal.

```
scm> (define outer (lambda (x y)
....   (define inner (lambda (z x)
....     (+ x (* y 2) (* z 3))))
....   (inner x 10)))
outer
scm> (outer 1 2)
17
scm> (define outer-func (lambda (x y)
....   (define inner (lambda (z x)
....     (+ x (* y 2) (* z 3))))
....   inner))
outer-func
scm> ((outer-func 1 2) 1 10)
# Error: unknown identifier: y
 
# Error: expected
#     17
# but got
#     Traceback (most recent call last):
#       ...
#     SchemeError: unknown identifier: y
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't bound the `outer-func` parameters in the environment where you apply `inner`. (You should evaluate function applications using the environment where it was defined; you need its `env` attribute.)

Comment: I trie to add this in eval to solve it, but it doesn't work, I just cannot figure out where I went wrong.

```
operator = scheme_eval(expr.first, env)
        # probleme9 I tried this to bound the values in the current frame 
        # if isinstance(operator, LambdaProcedure):
        #     return scheme_apply(operator, expr.rest, env)
        operands = expr.rest.map(lambda x: scheme_eval(x, env))
        return scheme_apply(operator, operands, env)
```

Comment: `scheme_eval`ing a procedure should store the environment of the definition in the resulting procedure object's `env` attribute. When you apply the procedure you extend this environment instead of the environment given to `scheme_eval`. (Read the description of the problem again.)